# Find second or third occurence of value in a specific row - excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I am trying to get the column position of a date that occurs more than once in a row.

Example data :
[image: data example].

The following formula correctly identifies most column positions, but if a duplicate is present, the first occurence's position is always returned.

The formula :
[image: The formula]

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

The following formula will select the `n-th` match in a set of matching and non-matching cells. It can be adapted to various source data layouts, more later. It is bare bones in that it does not provide any error checking at all, even your `IF(FL2<>0` portion since it is meant for a wide range of uses, but you can easily add in such checking to suit your exact circumstances:

```
=FILTERXML("<Outer><Inner>"&SUBSTITUTE(TEXTJOIN("¢",FALSE,FILTER(SUBSTITUTE(ADDRESS(ROW(),COLUMN(AW2:CW2),4),ROW(),""),AW2:CW2=B2),ROW(),""),"¢","</Inner><Inner>")&"</Inner></Outer>","/Outer/Inner["&C2&"]")
```

It is set up assuming it woul dgo in column A of a row with the value to match in column B and the `n-th` value in column C. Of course, you can adapt those.

A version using `LET()` to put all the variables in one easy-to-edit place is:

```
=LET(
 RangeToExamine, AW2:CW2,  Delimiter, "¢",  ItemToMatch, B2,  InstanceToMatch,  C2,
 FILTERXML("<Outer><Inner>"
 &SUBSTITUTE(TEXTJOIN(Delimiter,FALSE,
 FILTER(SUBSTITUTE(ADDRESS(ROW(),COLUMN(RangeToExamine),4),ROW(),""),
 RangeToExamine=ItemToMatch),
 ROW(),""),  Delimiter,"</Inner><Inner>") & "</Inner></Outer>",
 "/Outer/Inner["&InstanceToMatch&"]"))
```

That's all `LET()` is for:  to make the formula more easily edited.

So, what it does. First, although your layout might be a single row, I was not sure so I left it laid out to work on any row. That is taken care of by using the `ROW()` function inside the `ADDRESS()` function and later in a `SUBSTITUTE()` function that removes the row number (so you have column only which is your desired result). You could place a numeral "1" in both its places to ensure no row-wise activity occurs, if desired. You could even add a clause to the `LET()` if you wanted to be able to modify it here and there. I didn't here because it rolls the `LET()` line to two lines here and that'd make this messy. By the way, this is how you convert a column NUMBER to a column LETTER, not all those funny formulas with `MOD()` (and worse). No UDF's required.

So, `ADDRESS()` uses `Spill` functionality to make an array of all the cell addresses in the range being examined. `FILTER()` then examines the target range for matches and lists out the corresponding cell addresses. (Again, not set up for errors!) `SUBSTITUTE()` then strips off the row number (or the constant if you made that change) so Excel now has an array of just the column letter labels for the columns your matches were in.

I should make quick mention that the delimiter I used here is not necessarily always a good one — in other cases. But since it is not connected to the underlying data, but rather the address data, it only needs to be something never used in an address returned by `ADDRESS()` so it cannot fail here. Using the "rarely used character" approach elsewhere though, you might need to select something odd you find in Character Map.

Next, `TEXTJOIN()` turns the array of addresses into a string and `SUBSTITUTE()` replaces that delimiter with the `</Inner><Inner>` string while you also add string before and after to turn the result so far into acceptable XML. There could be almost anything used to structure the XML, so long as it is at least one higher level wrapping things and at least one lowest level wrapping each portion of the `TEXTJOIN()` string. I like to use `<Outer>` for the higher level that wraps it all, and `<Inner>` for the working level.

I first saw this somewhere with a very poorly laid out way of explaining it, but went to **Chandoo.org** to see if he had a tip on it since his explanations are (almost) always pretty clear and useful. It's been very handy, so I must give credit and thanks!

Finally, `FILTERXML()` does one last thing. It lets you pick which instance of the matches you want to return. In Chandoo's tip, he breaks down a sentence this way, but as you see, it can break down anything you get as or turn into a string, columnar data included. In this case, if you want a third instance, you'd add `[3]` to things.

However, Excel does us one better here. First, you can use the numerical instance, like [3] for the third instance, but you can also use `[last()]` to find the last instance without having to find its cardinal number too. But where the function really shines, surprisingly (since it wouldn't seem aimed at this kind of thing) is that you can "build" that clause, or put differently, you can build a string including variable data as part, that will then make your formula responsive instead of having to type it in and change it as needed inside the formula. That means your users can get that functionality using entries in cells rather than editing formulas. Or that you could make it reflect the outcome of some other formula if needed.

That last part happens in the last line of the formatted version of the formula. You give the "XML Path" (`/Outer/Inner" in this case) immediately followd by a set of square brackets ("[ ]") with the instance number or expression inside them.

In general use, I recommend error checking to look for:

1. Your item to match is not in the range being examined
2. The instance number you want is higher than the total matches:  you want #6, but only four exist...
3. Similarly, if you want to find the n-th instance back from the last instance, that it exist also:  if you want six back from "last()", that there be at least six others...

and that you take care with the delimiter you choose if the data is more varied than letter and numbers.

If you want a cell address instead of just a column, remove the `SUBSTITUTE()` that strips the row off the full address.

Well, sorry to an extent:  it IS a general solution rather than completely fitted to your post, but I was unsure the exact use you have and therefore that might also be helpful and any edits are pretty easy to see. Experience here shows posts leave out useful information very often and a poster must then ask at least one more question to get the answer he needed. Trying to short-circuit any need for you to go through that process.

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for COUNTIF formula? =IF(A2<>0,COUNTIF($A$2:A2,A2),0)

[image]